# Replacing Content in Fancybox on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, flash, mobile, fancybox

I'm working on a portfolio site that uses Fancybox to display my media content when the user clicks on a thumbnail. I have some Flash (.swf) files that I'd like to showcase, but since they don't work on iOS, I was wondering if there was a way to display some alternate content for that audience (maybe a message saying "Content not available on iOS devices" or something of that nature). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
// here validate if device is iOS
var _iOS = true; // true/false - for demo purposes
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            if (_iOS) {
                $.extend(this, {
                    content: "this content is not available for iOS devices",
                    type: "html"
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9cbu8d9o/)**